# How can I apply only some of a git stash?

Tags: git

I want to apply some of the changes in a git stash to one commit, and the rest of the changes to another.

Comment: What do you mean with "half"? Half of what? Half of each stash, or half of stash list?

Comment: Could it be by *half* you mean *a portion*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unstash the stash...

```
git stash pop
```

...use `git add` in patch mode...

```
git add -p
```

...and then commit that...

```
git commit -m "Partial stashed commit"
```

This is what quickly came to my head without reading the docs. [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281463/31671) has much better way to achieve this.

Comment: You could also restash unstaged changes but keep the index.

Comment: ^ Yes. @R0MANARMY suggests a good approach. Use `git stash --keep-index` to do this.

Comment: After doing this, I realized I wanted to follow [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884446/1048186) because I wanted to have my undesired changes still stashed, but my to-be-commited changes both in the working directory and index/cache/stage so that I could test them before committing them.

Answer (score 64):

```
git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

You can also do this with a list or a glob of filenames.

Comment: checkout is wrong if the stash is made from an earlier commit.

Comment: While this works, it overwrites <filename> with the version from the stash. You will need to manually resolve unrelated merge conflicts if the file has drifted, as pointed out by @nikolai.

Answer (score 29):

Looks like you can use `git checkout -p` with a stash reference, like  `stash@{0}`. This will let you choose piece by piece what you want to apply to your work tree from the stash.

After you're done using `git checkout -p`, the changes you accepted will have been applied to your work tree and added to the cache/index, ready to commit. You can use `git checkout -p stash@{0}` multiple times, choosing the patches you want and committing however many times you want along the way.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I think the other answers throw away changes from subsequent commits and/or working tree. Note that passing a path as well is very useful, particularly if your branch has been rebased since the stash. That helps avoid manually filtering out intervening changes (to other paths you don't need to restore) since the rebase.

Answer (score 12):

Apply the patch for only the files you want to change.

```
git show --first-parent stash@{0} -- <file(s) in question> | git apply
```

Comment: I think the default output has changed as you now need to specify the `-m` option (`git show -m stash...`) to output a diff that `git apply` understands. Without that I got `error: unrecognised input` from `git apply`.

Comment: @AndrewFrance I can't find much reference to `-m`. Can you point me to some documentation and I'll update my answer.

Comment: The documentation does seem lacking, `-m` is not in the options list on the man page for `git-show` but it is briefly mentioned in the [combined diff format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_combined_diff_format) section. It's not clear to me why it works sorry!

Comment: I think `-m` is for `git stash show` (having the same options as `git diff`), not for `git show stash`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for me either. `git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply` works if you do not need to select files. But `git stash show` doesn't accept filters on files and `git show` produces some "kind of patch of patch" that `git apply` doesn't understand.

Comment: @Cilyan I don't think you're copying my answer correctly. Try cut and paste rather than typing what you think it is. It's using the `git show` command, and showing `stash@{0}`. And if it truly isn't working, please supply the git version so that I can verify that it is no longer working.

Comment: `[cilyan@whatever repo]$ git show stash@{0} -- lib/drivers/****.c lib/include/drivers/*****.h | git apply`
gives `error: entrée non reconnue`. `git version 2.26.2`

Comment: @Cilyan I've reproduced the bug. Stashes are now saved as merge commits, it seems and produce a "combined diff". If I add `--first-parent` to the show command, it works again. Answer updated.