# git stash apply to specific files?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have two stashes that overlap. I think that if I apply both stashes, I will have a mess, because I don't need some changes in one of the stashes. So I would like to apply one stash and then apply only changes to specific files from another stash, even better if interactively. How can I do it?

My question is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212882) suggested, because the OP of that question wants apply stash to different commits, I want to apply two stashes to my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply only some of a git stash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212882/how-can-i-apply-only-some-of-a-git-stash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: how to use stash -p to stash specific files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704241/git-how-to-use-stash-p-to-stash-specific-files)

Answer (score 2):

Apply one stash, reset the files you don't want, commit the others, apply the second stash, reset the files from the first, commit.

Comment: The problem is that I have changes in both stashes to some same files, and I want them both, but they are conflicting. I don't mean that I want changes to only  specific files from specific stash

Comment: Apply the first, commit, apply the second (you will need to specify the stash), you will get a merge conflict if there are conflicting edits just like when merging, clean up the conflicts, commit.